# How to check an array of objects for a property value in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have an array of objects, and I'm trying to check if one of the objects in the array has a certain property value. If the property value is NOT found, I want to continue.

I am using `.some()` to check for the property value.

Here is my code:

```TypeScript
if (ticketsArray.some((ticket) => !(ticket.extId === '123'))) {
  // Do something here because the property value was not found
}
```

But with TypeScript the `ticket` object is throwing this error:

> Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)

Then I tried typing the `ticket` object like so:

```TypeScript
interface Ticket {
  extId: string;
}
if (ticketsArray.some((ticket: Ticket) => !(ticket.extId === '123'))) {
  // Do something here because the property value was not found
}
```

But TypeScript then throws this error:

> Argument of type '(ticket: Ticket) => boolean' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '(value: unknown, index: number, array: unknown[])
> => unknown'.   Types of parameters 'ticket' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Ticket'.ts(2345)

So what should I do?

Comment: what is the type of `ticketsArray`? If its type is `unknown[]`, that is the problem

Comment: Yes it is `unknown[]`! I will try and fix that now.

Comment: `ticketsArray: Ticket[]`